# Access Managed package class in an apex class or VF page

Tags: managed-package, controller-extension

I would want to access a managed package class in a VF page on the local org. All the methods and class are global and virtual in the managed package.

I have tried using . in the VF page
`controller ="<namespacename>.<classname>"` OR `extensions="<namespacename>.<classname>"`
also tried using `<namespacename>__<classname>`

it says `<namespacename>__<classname>` does not exist.

I have also tried extending the local controller class with

```
<localclassname> extends<namespacename>.<classname>
```

and it throws
Invalid type:`<namespacename>.<classname>`

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: I have not done this but I think you can call your org class and inside that class you can call the managed package methods. Your class here will work as a wrapper to manage package class.

Comment: Did you mean extend it?